# Conditional attachment of file using swiftmailer and symfony2

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I am currently working on attaching mails using swiftmailer. I need to attach a image file to the mail sometimes and sometimes I have to send the mail without the attachment.

This is what i tried

```
function sendMail($mailer,$subject , $to , $msg, $isAttachment, $attach)
    {
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom('abc@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('xyz@gmail.com')
        ->setBody($msg)
        ->setContentType("text/html");

    if($isAttachment){

            $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attach));
        }

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    }
```

`$isAttachment` is a Boolean variable which has `1` if there is a attachment.

This is the error I get.

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyProject\FrontBundle\Controller\Swift_Attachment' not found in /var/www/ABC/src/Myproject/FrontBundle/Controller/trialController.php on line 187
```

This is the first time i am working in swiftmailer .. So pardon me if this question sounds naive.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Namespacing problem. You did `\Swift_Message::newInstance` so you have to do:

```
$message->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attach));
```