# Attempted to load class "Swift_Attachment" with Swiftmailer

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using swiftmailer. Everything works fine. But if I add an attachment like this:

```
->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/images/products/' . $attachName))
```

I've an error: Attempted to load class "Swift_Attachment"

Any idea?

Comment: are you sure you set the USE statement for this class and cleared the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Conditional attachment of file using swiftmailer and symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453887/conditional-attachment-of-file-using-swiftmailer-and-symfony2/12454335)

Seems to be a namespacing problem, check how you called Swift_Message and try `->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/images/products/' . $attachName))`